# How can I create order in Pine Script with specific settings according to current price

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

It's kind of super simple task I guess, but I don't know how to do it yet.

I want to add a button on the graph which takes the current price and place an order with specific values based on that price.

Each help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `input.price()` [function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dprice) to determine variable that will be used for `strategy.entry()` condition.

e.g.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

price = input.price(0, confirm =  true)

if close > price*1.2 
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
```

Comment: This script does not actually place an order for me. Can you show me how to place order with Pine Script?

Comment: I mean to place Limit/Stop Order.

Comment: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#id6